# Hardware device to change musical tuning in the fly

Tags: audio, speakers, music, audio-adapters, sound-system

I am looking for a proper and recommended device to change [**musical tuning**](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_tuning) in the fly.

Let's say that I want some kind of music corrector connected to my home sound system and re-tune music playing at my home from `440 hz` into `432 hz` or `417 hz`.

Is there any good solution to do that?

What is the name of this kind of device and where to buy it?

I know that I can use some software (for example [**Audacity**](https://www.audacityteam.org/)) to change music frequency but I don't want to do that manually - I want to do that with some device connected to TV, speakers, etc..

Thank you for all you answers.

Comment: Any such device would need to be installed between the audio source input device and the amplifier. Do you have a separate amplifier, or does your existing sound system permit installing such a device?

Comment: This seems like a very trivial thing for a computer to handle with software by modifying the audio stream from its mic port and playing back to its speaker port. There are lots of options for software if you choose to use a computer instead of a dedicated device. (Even better if you play the audio from a computer in the first place)

Comment: @K7AAY, I'm just speaking of a computer with a mic and speaker jack, without assuming what those jacks are connected to. The line in or mic ports produce a digital stream *inside* the computer.

Comment: @K7AAY, You'd use the one that is more appropriate. Many soundcards can repurpose mic jacks as line-in jacks with a setting so it doesn't often matter. The frequency modification would be happening digitally, in the computer, before coming out the speaker jack.

Comment: @Romen _I want to do that with some device connected to TV, speakers, etc.._ is what the OP asked for.

Comment: @K7AAY, You can still use a computer for that too, I'm trying to say *it doesn't matter what they're using*. But I also pointed out that playing the audio from the computer in the first place would be the easiest way to accomplish this frequency shift without any special hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Standalone *pitch adjuster* devices like the [TC_Helicon](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/VoiceLiveR--tc-helicon-voicelive-rack) which can adjust pitch to the accuracy you specify are studio devices, designed to fit into a 19" rack mount frame. You'd need to interface them between the audio source and your amplifier, if your amplifier supports that. They will all be more expensive than used PC running tone adjustment apps.

Comment: I wonder if it'd doable with a DSP

Comment: This kind of DSP? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processing  That may be another question to pose at the software Q&A site http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have specific software and hardware in mind, might add another answer later. Problem is it replaces the sound card with a DAC which is not really too quality